# Prepend to an Iterable?

Tags: scala

How can I prepend, i.e. `cons`, to an `Iterable`?

```
scala> val xs: Iterable[Int] = Seq(1)
xs: Iterable[Int] = List(1)

scala> xs :: 5
<console>:15: error: value :: is not a member of Int
       xs :: 5
          ^
```

I looked at the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterable), but didn't figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`::` is specific to `List`. It *is* a `List`, in fact.

There is no concept of prepending to an `Iterable`, as not all `Iterable`s will guarantee order (`Set` does not, for example). You may want `Seq` instead, which would use `+:` to prepend.

Comment: I like this answer better than mine. You want to use a `Seq`.

Comment: I looked to an Iterable since I hand-rolled the sequence function (from scalaz/haskell) with a Seq. But then I had a set, so I took the LUB of Set and Seq - which is Iterable.

Comment: The best you can do with `Iterable` is concatenate using `++`, which will not necessarily prepend or keep the order.

Comment: Saying ":: is a List" is misleading in this context. The method "List.::" and the case class "::" are distinct concepts.

Answer (score 3):

`Iterable` doesn't have a `prepend` method, but you can use "++" to join two iterables:

```
scala> val xs: Iterable[Int] = Seq(1)
xs: Iterable[Int] = List(1)

scala> List(5) ++ xs
res0: List[Int] = List(5, 1)
```

`Seq` does have a prepend method, `+:`, and you could convert to a seq:

```
scala> 5 +: xs.toSeq
res1: Seq[Int] = List(5, 1)
```